# How do I remove retweets after I have scraped and saved them in *.csv, and how do I remove duplicate tweets?

Tags: r, twitter, tweets

I have collected a large amount of Tweets. In the scraping process while using `(twitteR)` I did not add `(-filter:retweet)` in my code. Now I have a data set and I want to remove tweets that are retweeted. In the set the `columnname` is called `isRetweet`, and I want to remove all tweets that are: 
`isRetweet = TRUE`

Further, I have Tweets that are **duplicates** and want to remove them.

Any help is welcome, even just pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: First part solved by using `(dplyr)`.

`set1<- set %>%filter(!str_detect(isRetweet, "TRUE"))`

Comment: `distinct(set1)`  removes duplicate rows from `set1`. See `?distinct()` for alternatives.

Comment: @deepseefan Thank you very much. `distinct()` function lets me keep unique tweets.